# Find Strings that contains a sequence of a specific sub string, with a limited amount of interruptions in between with regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm looking for the following regex:
to find the part of the string (if exist) that contains the longest sequence of repeating `GGG`, with a minimal interruption of 10 chars in between every `GGG`. 
i tried the following pattern but it didn't work that well: `((GGG).{0,10}?)*`

`CAGTTAGGGTTTAGGGTTAGGTTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTGAGGTGAGGGTGAGGGTTAGGGTGAGGGGTGAGGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGAGTTGCAGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGGTTAGGGTTACTTTAGGGTTAGGGTTGGGGGTTTAGGGTTTAGGGTTTAGGGTTTAGGGTTTAGGGTTAGAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTACCTGCTTACTTGCTGCAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAAGTTAGGGTTTAGGGTTGGGGTTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTGAGGTTAGGGTTAGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTGCAGGGTTAGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGGTTAGGGGTTGGGGGGGTTAGGGTTGGGGGTTGGGGGTTAGGGAGGGTTAGGGGTTGGGGGTTGCAGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTACCTTGGGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTGCAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGAGTTAGGGTTAGAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTTAGGGTTAGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGTTAGAGGTTAGGGTTAGGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGGTTGGGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGTTGCAGAAGGGGTTGAGCAGGGTGGGAGTTAGGGATTAGGGATTAGGAGTTAGGGTGAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTGGGGTGGGGATTGGGGATTGGGAGTTAGGGTGGGTGGGGATTGGGGAGTTAGGAGTTAGGAGTTAGGAGTTAGGGAGTTAGGTTAGGGAGTTAGGGTTAGGAGTTAGAGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTGGGAGTTAGGGAGTTAGGAGGTGGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGAGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGATTGGGAGTTAGGGTAGGAGTTAGGGTTAGAGGTTAGGAGTTAGGGTTAGGAGTTAGGGATTAGAGGTTAGGGTGGGATTAGGAGTTACTTACTTAGGGAGTTAGGAGTTAGGAGTTAGGGTGGGGTGGGAGTTAGAGGTTAGGAGTTAGGAGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGAGTTAAGGGTTAGGGATTAGGAGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGAGTTAGGGAGTTAGGGTGGGGTGGGAGTTGCAGGGATTGGGTTAGGGTTAGGAGTTGGGAGTTGGGGAGTTGGGAGTTAGGGTTACAGGGTGGGAGTTAGGAGTTAGGGAGTTAGGAGTTAGAGGTTAGGGATTAGGGGT`

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will work based on your rules: `((?:GGG.{0,10}?)+GGG)`

[**regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/f6Hz6v/1)

Explanation:

- `(` start capture group

  - `(?:` start non-capturing group

    - `GGG` literally
    - `.{0,10}?` any character 0-10 times, non-greedy
  - `)` end the non-capturing group
  - `+` match the previous group 1 or more times
  - `GGG` literally
- `)` end the capture group

Then you can simply use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to find all of those matches, and get the longest one of those with [`max(key=len)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max).

Python demo:

```
import re

string = "CAGTTAGGGTTTAGGGTTAGGTTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTGAGGTGAGGGTGAGGGTTAGGGTGAGGGGTGAGGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGAGTTGCAGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGGTTAGGGTTACTTTAGGGTTAGGGTTGGGGGTTTAGGGTTTAGGGTTTAGGGTTTAGGGTTTAGGGTTAGAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTACCTGCTTACTTGCTGCAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAAGTTAGGGTTTAGGGTTGGGGTTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTGAGGTTAGGGTTAGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTGCAGGGTTAGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGGTTAGGGGTTGGGGGGGTTAGGGTTGGGGGTTGGGGGTTAGGGAGGGTTAGGGGTTGGGGGTTGCAGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTACCTTGGGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTGCAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGAGTTAGGGTTAGAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTTAGGGTTAGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGTTAGAGGTTAGGGTTAGGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGGTTGGGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGTTGCAGAAGGGGTTGAGCAGGGTGGGAGTTAGGGATTAGGGATTAGGAGTTAGGGTGAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTGGGGTGGGGATTGGGGATTGGGAGTTAGGGTGGGTGGGGATTGGGGAGTTAGGAGTTAGGAGTTAGGAGTTAGGGAGTTAGGTTAGGGAGTTAGGGTTAGGAGTTAGAGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTGGGAGTTAGGGAGTTAGGAGGTGGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGAGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGATTGGGAGTTAGGGTAGGAGTTAGGGTTAGAGGTTAGGAGTTAGGGTTAGGAGTTAGGGATTAGAGGTTAGGGTGGGATTAGGAGTTACTTACTTAGGGAGTTAGGAGTTAGGAGTTAGGGTGGGGTGGGAGTTAGAGGTTAGGAGTTAGGAGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGAGTTAAGGGTTAGGGATTAGGAGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGAGTTAGGGAGTTAGGGTGGGGTGGGAGTTGCAGGGATTGGGTTAGGGTTAGGAGTTGGGAGTTGGGGAGTTGGGAGTTAGGGTTACAGGGTGGGAGTTAGGAGTTAGGGAGTTAGGAGTTAGAGGTTAGGGATTAGGGGT"
pattern = re.compile(r"((?:GGG.{0,10}?)+GGG)")

longest = max(re.findall(pattern, string), key=len)
print(len(longest), longest)
```

Output:

> ```
> 583 GGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAAGTTAGGGTTTAGGGTTGGGGTTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTGAGGTTAGGGTTAGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTGCAGGGTTAGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGGTTAGGGGTTGGGGGGGTTAGGGTTGGGGGTTGGGGGTTAGGGAGGGTTAGGGGTTGGGGGTTGCAGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTACCTTGGGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTGCAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGAGTTAGGGTTAGAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTTAGGGTTAGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGTTAGAGGTTAGGGTTAGGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGGTTGGGGGTTGGGGTTAGGGTTGCAGAAGGGGTTGAGCAGGGTGGGAGTTAGGGATTAGGG
> ```

Edit:
If you want to have at least 51 `GGG`s in the string, you can use the pattern: `((?:GGG.{0,10}?){50,}GGG)` to accomplish that.

Comment: Thank you! could you explain me the logic behind this pattern? symbols wise?

Comment: and may i add one more condition? i would like this longest sub-string to get matched only if the GGG appears in it more than 50 times total (may not be like that in my example string)

Comment: @LiorPaz Added an explanation and the pattern which has to have >50 `GGG`.

Comment: Thank you again. im running these on huge amounts of data, and speed is crucial. do you believe `re.findall` is the fastest way, or maybe `search` or `match` would do better?

Comment: `re.findall` is the only way to do it like this.